# How can I cumulate _.zip, _.map _.reduce operations?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Given a JSON as this one :

```
var data = {
  "entries": [
    {
      "fund": 1,
      "values": [
        { "name": "alm1", "splits": [ 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
        { "name": "alm2", "splits": [ 0,   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
      ]
   },
    {
      "fund": 2,
      "values": [
        { "name": "alm1", "splits": [ 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
        { "name": "alm2", "splits": [ 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
        { "name": "alm3", "splits": [ 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I would be able to set "sums" property as it with lodash/underscore :

```
var expected = {
  "entries": [
    {
      "fund": 1,
      "values": [
        { "name": "alm1", "splits": [ 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
        { "name": "alm2", "splits": [ 0,   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
      ],
      "sums":                       [ 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   },
    {
      "fund": 2,
      "values": [
        { "name": "alm1", "splits": [ 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
        { "name": "alm2", "splits": [ 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
        { "name": "alm3", "splits": [ 2,   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }
      ],
      "sums":                       [ 4,   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }
  ],
  "sums":                           [ 4.5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
};
```

I've tried different methods with lodash, without success.
_.map(), _.reduce() or _.zip()

Is it possible to cumulate/chain call to obtain the expected result?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [unzip()](https://lodash.com/docs#unzip) is better suited for what you're doing:

```
var a1 = [ 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    a2 = [ 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    a3 = [ 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];

_([a1, a2, a3])
    .unzip()
    .map(_.sum)
    .value()
// → [4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```